# Scala Reactive Extensions Observable apply Method

Tags: scala, rx-scala

From the API docs of Rx Observable in scala:

http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/#rx.lang.scala.Observable

There are two apply methods, one that takes a Subscriber and the other that takes an Observer. What is the difference between these two apply methods other than the fact that they take in different types to subscribe to an Observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Subscriber's documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Subscriber):

```
abstract class Subscriber[-T] extends Observer[T] with Subscription
```

> An extension of the Observer trait which adds subscription handling
>   (unsubscribe, isUnsubscribed, and add methods) and backpressure
>   handling (onStart and request methods).

So we can assume that [`Observer`'s `apply`](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observable@apply(observer:rx.lang.scala.Observer[T]):rx.lang.scala.Subscription) is more general binding which could take some proxied or self-defined [observers](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observer) and implements [the observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), while [`Subscriber`'s `apply`](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observable@apply(subscriber:rx.lang.scala.Subscriber[T]):rx.lang.scala.Subscription) is more efficient internal binding.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664221/what-is-the-difference-between-an-observer-and-a-subscriber) for the details.